# puppet code to detect -v switch to add to command to be run

Tags: puppet

Firstly I am new to puppet and I've inherited some code and I honestly don't think this has ever actually worked.  I've done my best to debug and understand it but really could do with a bit of help.

In modules\hieradata\server_environment_class\pre_production.yaml I have the below code…

```
##### MongoDB Vars #####
eikonappmongodb::primary_node: 'c784smseatg01.int.xxxxxxx.com'
eikonappmongodb::arbiter_node: 'betamongodb05.amers3.xxxxxx'
eikonappmongodb::voter_node:
  - c425cpaeatg02.int.xxxxxx.com
  - c687ucweatg03.int.xxxxxx.com
```

In modules\appmongodb\manifests\init.pp I have the below code.

```
$is_arbiter = $::fqdn ? {
  $arbiter_node => true,
  default       => false,
}

if is_string($voter_node) {
  if inline_template('<%= @voter_node.any?{ |node| node.casecmp(@fqdn)==0 } %>') {
    $is_voter = true
  } else {
    $is_voter = false
  }
} else {
  $is_voter = false
}

if $is_arbiter {
  exec { 'addArbiterToReplicaSet':
    command => "/n01/mongodb/bin/rsAddMe.sh -s ${primary_node} -r ${replSetName} -p ${adm_pwd} -a ${::fqdn}",
    unless  => "/n01/mongodb/bin/mongo --host localhost --norc --quiet --eval 'rs.status().code' | wc -l | grep 0",
    require => File['/n01/mongodb/bin/rsAddMe.sh'],
  }
} else {
  if is_string($voter_node) {
    $voter_param = ' -v '
  } else {
    $voter_param = ' '
  }

  exec { 'addDataToReplicaSet':
    command => "/n01/mongodb/bin/rsAddMe.sh -s ${primary_node} -r ${replSetName} -p ${adm_pwd} ${voter_param} ${::fqdn}",
    unless  => "/n01/mongodb/bin/mongo --host localhost -u admin -p ${adm_pwd} --authenticationDatabase admin --norc --quiet --eval 'rs.status().code'",
    require => File['/n01/mongodb/bin/rsAddMe.sh'],
  }
}
```

So from what I’ve tried so far running on server c425cpaeatg02 it’s correctly not determined as an arbiter which is great.

The problem I’m having is when running `command => "/n01/mongodb/bin/rsAddMe.sh -s ${primary_node} -r ${replSetName} -p ${adm_pwd} ${voter_param} ${::fqdn}"`, from `addDataToReplicaSet`.
The `$voter_param` is not being populated as `–v` which it should be which breaks the command.
So the code here…

```
if is_string($voter_node) {
  $voter_param = ' -v '
} else {
  $voter_param = ' '
}
```

Would appear to not be working.

Comment: The code does appear like it would have been functioning at some point, but it is so poorly written that I am unsurprised if some change in your environment broke it. Since the module name and Hiera key names are inconsistent, this must not be using automatic lookup/data bindings. How is this module finding information from Hiera?

Comment: Hi Matt - we have another yaml file mapped to a servertype.  the yaml file includes the classes.

Comment: That doesn't explain how the Hiera lookups are being performed though.